# BST says the tree has been populated but when i use the find function it does not iterate through any of the nodes C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

my main.cpp:

```
    BinarySearchTree<int> b = BinarySearchTree<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        b.add(i);
    }

    b.find(45);
```

the output is depth of target value is: 0

BinarySearchTree.h file. the code should work as it was given working by professor. we have to modify the find function to store the depth of last node visited. I have implemented as such:

```
bool find(const Comparable& c, BinaryNode* n) const {
        int lastNode = 0;
        if (n == nullptr) {
            // Reached a dead end. Value not in tree.
            std::cout << "Depth of last node visited: " << lastNode - 1;
            return false;
        }
        if (c < n->value) {
            // Value is less than current node. Go to node's left child.
            lastNode += 1;
            return find(c, n->leftChild);
        }
        if (n->value < c) {
            // Value is greater than current node. Go to node's right child.
            lastNode += 1;
            return find(c, n->rightChild);
        }
        // If code reaches here, c == n->value. Node found!
        std::cout << "Depth of target value: " << lastNode;
        return true;
    }
```

I have added the add function in the BinarySearchTree.h file as well for everyones reference below.

```
  // Helper recursive function to add a value to the tree.
    void add(const Comparable& c, BinaryNode* &n) {
        if (n == nullptr) {
            // We found the place where we can add the node.
            n = new BinaryNode(c, nullptr, nullptr);
        }
        else if (c < n->value) {
            // Value is less than current node. Go to left child.
            add(c, n->leftChild);
        }
        else if (n->value < c) {
            // Value is greater than current node. Go to right child.
            add(c, n->rightChild);
        }
        // If code reaches here, value is a duplicate. Nothing to do.
    }
```

I am trying to figure out why the ints from 1 to 100 and are not being added even though i tested using an isEmpty function which came back false as the tree was populated.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 1):

You never pass the value of `lastNode` down to recursive calls. When you recursively call `find`, each call has its own `lastNode` initialized to 0. The first time the value is found none of the if statements in `find` will execute and you'll fall through to the last bit where you print a message and `return true;`. This return will end up propagating all the way back up the stack and terminating the search without printing anything else.

You need to tell each recursive call what its depth is. One way would be to provide an extra parameter:

```
bool find(const Comparable& c, BinaryNode* n, int depth = 0) const {
    if (n == nullptr) {
        // Reached a dead end. Value not in tree.
        std::cout << "Depth of last node visited: " << depth - 1;
        return false;
    }
    if (c < n->value) {
        // Value is less than current node. Go to node's left child.
        return find(c, n->leftChild, depth + 1);
    }
    if (n->value < c) {
        // Value is greater than current node. Go to node's right child.
        return find(c, n->rightChild, depth + 1);
    }
    // If code reaches here, c == n->value. Node found!
    std::cout << "Depth of target value: " << depth;
    return true;
}
```